# Accessing iSight via Java on OSX

Tags: java, macos, isight

So after doing a lot of digging around here, and elsewhere, there is no good, simple, CURRENT way to grab images from iSight in Java. So first of all I would love if someone could point me to a good way to do this, and OpenCV does not work for Java in case you were thinking of that.

Here's a workaround of sorts that I'm thinking about using, even though it is incredibly flawed:

1. Open up Photo Booth
2. Use java's Robot class to grab an image of the portion of the screen that holds the feed from the iSight.

Comment: Have you considered JNI?

Comment: OpenCV is a library that can be used with any language that has bindings for it. See http://code.google.com/p/javacv/. You'd be much better off doing this in native Objective-C if that is an option.

Comment: @MikeKwan Hmmm....I'm looking at JNI right now. That looks like it adds many layers of complexity. I can't find any tutorials on using that to grab iSight do you know of any. I don't know Objective-C and after a few failed attempts at learning it I have zero desire to ever do anything in it.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to capture single pictures, you could use a command line program like [imagesnap](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/), run it with `Runtime.exec`, save the picture to a temp directory, then open the image file.